# browse list and add condition

Tags: c#

i have a function that return list of ip and his port this is the function :

```
public static List<ServerSocks> loadSocks()
{
    var result = new List<ServerSocks>();
    string fileSocks = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "socks-list.txt"));
    var input = File.ReadAllText(fileSocks);
    var r = new Regex(@"(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}):(\d{1,5})");
    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(input))
    {
        string ip = match.Groups[1].Value;
        int port = Convert.ToInt32(match.Groups[2].Value);

        ServerSocks bi = new ServerSocks();
        bi.IpAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
        bi.Port = port;
        result.Add(bi);

    }
   return result;
}
```

i want a random value from list to be the proxy settings for my oServer

```
List<ServerSocks> list;       
List<ServerSocks> list = loadSocks();
SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("");
foreach (var item in list)
{                                               
    oServer.SocksProxyServer = Convert.ToString(item.IpAddress);
    oServer.SocksProxyPort = item.Port;                  
}
```

i do like this but always he give me the last ip and his port.

What i should do ??

thanks .

Comment: your loop `foreach (var item in list)` runs through completely, therefore it will finish with the last item. which item do you want?

Comment: Well, the foreach loop will loop through and set the oServer.SocksProxyServer and oServer.SocksProxyPort to the various values of the list, but if you try getting the Object Properties after the foreach loop it will only give you the last, since that's the last values it sets to the Object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that you set `oServer.SocksProxyServer` when you first enter the loop and all consecutive runs overwrites the value. It does cycle through all your `List<ServerSocks>`

If you want to convert to a list of `oServer` then you'd create a new list outside the loop and do this inside the loop:

`Add(new OServer { SocksProxyServer=item.IpAddress.ToString(), SocksProxyPort=item.Port })`

It'd be great if you'd explain what you want to happen in more detail. I hope this helps you though.

**Edit**
You don't need a loop at all. It's sufficient to get a random index and retrieve the corresponding item.

```
var oServer = new SmtpServer("");
var random = new Random();
var randomIndex = random.Next(list.Count);
var socks = list[randomIndex];
oServer.SocksProxyServer = socks.IpAddress;
oServer.SocksProxyPort = socks.Port;
```

Comment: i want that foreach return for me one ip and his port , and i affect them to the properties SocksProxyServer and SocksProxyPort thnks

Comment: SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer(""); oServer is an instance of class smtp server

Comment: So you want something to happen to the `SmtpServer` object with each item in your `List<ServerSocks>`?

Comment: yes the value that return List<ServerSocks> , iwant to affect them to the proprties oServer.SocksProxyServer = ip returned by list and oServer.SocksProxyPort = port returned by list

Comment: So what makes the last value less desireable than, say, the first one? It seems to me that you want a random value from the list to be the proxy settings for your `oServer`. But if you want to set the proxy, then do something, go to the next value, set the proxy, do something, [...] then you should add method calls to `oServer` inside the loop, after setting the proxy settings. I'm really sorry if I keep misunderstanding your intentions here.

Comment: yes this what i want ,i want a random value from list   to be the proxy settings for my oServer

Comment: `var random = new Random();` then `var socks = list[rand.Next(list.Count)];` instead of the loop. That'll give you random settings in the new `socks` object, thus `oServer.SocksProxyServer = socks.IpAddress.ToString();`.

Comment: thank you it s work very nice, do you have an account in skybe

Comment: I do, but I can't be your code supporter, sorry :) There's a great amount of people here on SO that'll try to answer any question you might have. Just be sure to describe what the problem is, what you have tried, and what you expect in as precise detail (including relevant parts of code is nice) as you can and you'll get great answers in no time.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve what you want to do, do this:

```
List<ServerSocks> list = loadSocks();

Random rnd = new Random();
int r = rnd.Next(list.Count);

oServer.SocksProxyServer = Convert.ToString(list[r].IpAddress);
oServer.SocksProxyPort = list[r].Port;
```

Then it will take a random Object from the ServerSocks list and use.

Comment: i edit my code if you see SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("");
 oServer is an instance of class SmtpServer

Comment: Yes, but if you look at the code in my answer, it all Depends on WHEN you utilize that oServer Object. I Guess you try to do something With it later on in the code, but in that case, encapsulate what you do within the foreach loop. Right now it loops over all the values in the list and sets the oServer Object to each value of the ServerSocks list ending up With setting it to the last value, when you later on use that oServer Object it will only have the last provided value from the list, unless you execute what you need oServer for within the foreach, then it will do it for each of the items.

Comment: I think we would be able to give you a much clearer answer if we knew what you are going to use the oServer Object for in the code. Is it to try out different servers for sending an email?

Comment: i want a random value from list to be the proxy settings for my oServer